# Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

On my development machine I don't have a problem. However when I load the same form up on my production server I get error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a`

If i remove the following code it will work fine in my production server.

```
$scope.grid = function(targetElement) {
    var $div = $('<div style="height:375px; top:-1%; position: absolute; width:100%; " ><div reports  data-uri="repouri" data-form-data="formData"   data-show-filter="false" data-field="[]" ></div></div>');
    targetElement.append($div);

    angular.element(targetElement).injector().invoke(function($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
        $compile($div)(scope);
    });
};
```

Is there any solution to fix this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is wiring up what I assume is a directive, please paste the code for the directive reports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an error on production because over there your code is minified, hence `$compile` is named differently thus hurting the [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) mechanism of Angular.

You need to do this to resolve:

```
angular.element(targetElement).injector().invoke(['$compile', function($compile) {
    var scope = angular.element($div).scope();
    $compile($div)(scope);
}]);
```

Comment: Wow, minification in production and not in dev environment, well spotted.